# docker-compose up hangs performing system checks

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I entered "docker-compose up". It executes but hangs after this line of output:

```
app_1  |   Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

I've tried pruning my containers and rerunning but always get stuck here. 
Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python3 manage.py wait_for_db &&
             python3 manage.py migrate &&
             python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=app
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASS=supersecretpassword
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=app
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
```

And here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
MAINTAINER Josh Doyle

ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
    gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp-build-deps

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

Here is the entire console output:

```
recipe-app-api on  master [⇡!?] on  v19.03.5 () via  3.8.1 took 7s
➜ docker-compose up
recipe-app-api_db_1 is up-to-date
Creating recipe-app-api_app_1 ... done
Attaching to recipe-app-api_db_1, recipe-app-api_app_1
db_1   | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db_1   | This user must also own the server process.
db_1   |
db_1   | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db_1   | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db_1   | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db_1   |
db_1   | Data page checksums are disabled.
db_1   |
db_1   | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
db_1   | creating subdirectories ... ok
db_1   | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db_1   | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db_1   | selecting default timezone ... UTC
db_1   | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db_1   | creating configuration files ... ok
db_1   | running bootstrap script ... ok
db_1   | sh: locale: not found
db_1   | 2020-03-10 17:20:52.053 UTC [29] WARNING:  no usable system locales were found
db_1   | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db_1   | syncing data to disk ... ok
db_1   |
db_1   | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1   | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db_1   | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1   |
db_1   | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1   |
db_1   |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1   |
db_1   | waiting for server to start....2020-03-10 17:20:53.324 UTC [34] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2020-03-10 17:20:53.342 UTC [35] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-03-10 17:20:52 UTC
db_1   | 2020-03-10 17:20:53.349 UTC [34] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server started
db_1   | CREATE DATABASE
db_1   |
db_1   |
db_1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db_1   |
db_1   | waiting for server to shut down....2020-03-10 17:20:53.908 UTC [34] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db_1   | 2020-03-10 17:20:53.912 UTC [34] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db_1   | 2020-03-10 17:20:53.914 UTC [34] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 41) exited with exit code 1
db_1   | 2020-03-10 17:20:53.915 UTC [36] LOG:  shutting down
db_1   | 2020-03-10 17:20:53.937 UTC [34] LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server stopped
db_1   |
db_1   | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1   |
db_1   | 2020-03-10 17:20:54.028 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2020-03-10 17:20:54.028 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2020-03-10 17:20:54.033 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2020-03-10 17:20:54.055 UTC [45] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-03-10 17:20:53 UTC
db_1   | 2020-03-10 17:20:54.059 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
app_1  | Waiting for database...
app_1  | Database available.
app_1  | Operations to perform:
app_1  |   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, core, sessions
app_1  | Running migrations:
app_1  |   Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
app_1  |   Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
app_1  |   Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
app_1  |   Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
app_1  |   Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
app_1  |   Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
app_1  |   Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
app_1  |   Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
app_1  |   Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
app_1  |   Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
app_1  |   Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
app_1  |   Applying core.0001_initial... OK
app_1  |   Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
app_1  |   Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
app_1  |   Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
app_1  |   Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

If I run docker-compose up again without pruning then I hang after the output "No migrations to apply".
I've researched this quite a bit but I haven't found an answer. I appreciate the help you might provide.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. You must provide Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files to be more clear

Comment: Thanks. Updated original post. Sorry. New to S/O and docker.

Comment: @JoshDoyle what's your host operating system? did you check that it does not resource issue? (more CPU/RAM)

Comment: I'm on macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact the normal behaviour for `docker-compose` where you are running in attach mode. In this mode, `docker-compose` will print out all the `stdout` and `stderr` of all the docker containers that it spins up. When the containers stop printing out logs to `stdout` or `stderr`, it gives the impression that the `docker-compose` command hangs but they are in fact running normally.

1 thing to note with this mode is that once you `cmd + C` to stop the `docker-compose`, all the containers will be stopped (but not killed) as well and hence, the next time that you run `docker-compose up`, there will be no migration to apply since the database is already up to date.

To keep your containers running, you should run your command in detach mode like this:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

To stop and remove all the containers for this project, run:

```
docker-compose down -v
```